# Specify User that hits Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, symfony

I am making calls to google analytics, whilst building the project everything has been fine, I can call data just fine. Now with calling realtime data there is a 10k requests per day from one user.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/limits-quotas#overview

In my project i have 3 different logins that show three different templates with all sorts of data, on each page i am making an ajax call to pull the data into the certain template. again this logic is working great and as expected. but when i test the app with all three users logged in and making the calls within a few hours the 10k limit will soon be hit.

So I did my research and discovered that the 10K requests is per day and also per GA user. Now i am trying to create separate users in Google analytics for each user in my project and for the ajax calls that i make in my templates, for those calls i would like to of course hit the API authorized as the relevant user.

This is where i'm running into a wall, i find it confusing on how to create a new user under the same GA account and auth myself as that user when hitting the API

I shall show my controller that makes calls for reference for anyone if needed below

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Api;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Google_Client;

class GAGetVistorsCount
{
protected $key;
protected $email;

public function __construct($key, $email)
{
    $this->key      = $key;
    $this->email    = $email;
}

public function __invoke()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();

    $gaAuth = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';
    $keyfile = file_get_contents($this->key);

    $client->setApplicationName('TeamRock-Dashboard');
    $client->setAssertionCredentials(new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
              $this->email,[$gaAuth],$keyfile
            ));
    $analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    $optParams = array(
        'dimensions' => 'rt:medium'
    );

    $apiCall = $analytics->data_realtime->get('ga:<profileView>', 'rt:activeVisitors', $optParams);
    $data = $apiCall->getTotalsForAllResults();

    return new Response(
        $data['rt:activeVisitors']
    );
  }
}
```

Any help, pointers, tips or suggestions would be appreciated, been at this for a couples of days now getting stressful :')

Answer (score 0):

I believe that requests are limited per View, rather than per User.

In any case, I believe attempting to circumvent Google's API limits is not a good idea. In my opinion, it tends to reflect that you are misusing either the API or the free service provided by Google. I recommend that you rethink your approach. Why do you need to make so many requests?

Try to cut yourself down to one request per template per day, and make sure that you store this data appropriately, so that you don't ever have to pull the same data more than once.

Comment: You are correct with the limit per view: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#core_reporting